# How to parse the "request body" using python CGI?

Tags: python, parsing, cgi, request

I just need to write a simple python CGI script to parse the contents of a POST request containing JSON.  This is only test code so that I can test a client application until the actual server is ready (written by someone else).

I can read the cgi.FieldStorage() and dump the keys() but the request body containing the JSON is nowhere to be found.

I can also dump the os.environ() which provides lots of info except that I do not see a variable containing the request body.

Any input appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're using CGI, just read data from `stdin`:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works great! I searched but never saw this one. Thank you!

Comment: helps a lot! awesome!

Comment: the data is blank when I send a post request with data in the body

Answer (score 8):

notice that if you call `cgi.FieldStorage()` before in your code, you can't get the body data from stdin, because it just be read once.